# Why do I need Keyword "this" in method of the class? in my case?

Tags: c#

I study c# from a little bit old book, but it is nice book, here the author use *this* keyword to modify or call the field of the class but actually even if I delete *this* keyword from the method it works perfect. when do I need this keyword actually?

```
Dog dog = new();
System.Console.WriteLine(dog.GetAge());
dog.MakeOlder();
System.Console.WriteLine(dog.GetAge());


class Dog{
    int age = 2;

    // Field Declaration
    public int GetAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
    public void MakeOlder(){
        this.age++;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing answers before posting, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%23+when+do+I+need+this+keyword).

Comment: this keyword make the semantics clearer

Comment: question in title seems odd, when you have already figured out, by deleting this, that you don’t need it at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) keyword is used to increase the readability, in your case. Of the other reasons, it can also be used to distinguish another variable, when its shadowing the member variable.

For example:

```
class Student{
    String name;
    int age;

    public SetStudent(string name, int age){
         this.name = name;
         this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Here, the parameters passed to `SetStudent` shadows the member variables. To distinguish between both `this` keyword is used here. Although its a bad practice to keep the parameter name same as member variable name.